# lots of different domain names, 1 server

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, redirect

Is it possible to redirect domain names which already point to the same server?

For example, if my main website is www.companyname.com, and I have another domainname as www.companyname2.com, if I go to www.companyname2.com, I don't want users to see that domainname, I want them to be redirected to www.companyname.com, even though they both are the same website.

I am using RedHat linux and have a LAMP configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do it like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.companyname2.com
ServerAlias companyname2.com 
Redirect permanent / http://www.companyname.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do I need to restart apache after making this change?

Comment: Yes, I had to restart apache, but the script above puts the website into an infinite loop.

Comment: What does your access log say is happening?